MS Excel: count if difference between two numbers is in a range, and a third number is within another range
Please could you help me with a tricky (in my book) Excel problem. I have a database of numbers, where I need to count how many cases there are where a subtraction of numbers falls within a range, and then a different number is within a specified range.
For instance:
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   3   6   30      Max 20
2   1   3   21      Min 10
3   5   10  35          
4   3   9   12          

Column B is always be greater than column A (they are dates).
I need to know how many rows where, for instance, B-A is between 2 and 4, and C is between the specified max and min in column F. In this example it would be 1 (row 2).
Using =SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B-A:A<=4))-SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B-A:A>=2)) I can get the first condition to work, but how do I then add the second condition?
I don't want to add any calculation rows to the database (I am trying to auto calculate from a cut/paste situation for others).
I don't (sadly) have MS365
Thank you!
Patrick
Using =SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B-A:A<=4))-SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B-A:A>=2)) I can get the first condition to work, but how do I then add the second condition?

You can just combine all conditions in a single SUMPRODUCT:
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B-A:A>=2)*(B:B-A:A<=4)*(C:C>=F2)*(C:C<=F1))

